# Install python package and it says "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed"?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, python3

I want to install python package 'pygame'.Using python3.5,I install these following first:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev mercurial
$ sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev
$ pip3 install --user hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

and it shows these:

```
    The directory '/home/omou/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory 
is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. 
Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing 
pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/omou/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not 
owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check 
the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with 
sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
  Cloning hg http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame to /tmp/pip-7bSGiX-
build
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:


WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
Using UNIX configuration...

sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
sh: 1: freetype-config: not found

Hunting dependencies...
WARNING: "freetype-config" failed!
SDL     : found 1.2.15
FONT    : found
IMAGE   : found
MIXER   : found
PNG     : found
JPEG    : found
SCRAP   : found
PORTMIDI: found
PORTTIME: found
FREETYPE: not found
Missing dependencies

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
/tmp/pip-7bSGiX-build/
```

I've tried so many mathods, and it won't fixd.Please somebody tell me what's going on and how to fix it .

Comment: Not a native English speaker, if you don't understand my question I can leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the output, you are not the one who installed pip. Maybe you should change to another account to use pip. Or use sudo to promote permission.

Comment: It's the same, and I've reinstall pip quite many times. And I tried the '-H' either, the begining words gone, but rest wasn't change.

Comment: maybe you could refer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869101/unable-to-install-pygame-using-pip#

Comment: It work!So appreciate about that!